# Create interface for user input

Tags: qgis, python, widget, dialog, input

I want to do something like this using Python and QGIS:
[image]
And I want to save what user input in each field in 4 variables.
Here is what I tried but it is not giving what I want:

```
import sys

class Dialog(QDialog):
    NumGridRows = 3
    NumButtons = 4

    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        self.createFormGroupBox()
        
        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Form Layout - pythonspot.com")
        
    def createFormGroupBox(self):
        self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox("Form layout")
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Street:"), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Apartment:"), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Post code:"), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("City:"), QLineEdit())
        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = Dialog()
sys.exit(dialog.exec_())
```

But gives this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

QGIS dhas a plugin called PlugIn Builder3 that is very useful to create your template. Along with with QT designer will allow you to make great looking GUI's.  It also has has custom QGIS widgets.

Search around [here](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/index.html) (https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins/index.html?highlight=plugin)  a bit and other QGIS PlugIn areas / tutorials.   There are a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want your form to have a grid layout. I would suggest taking a look at [this tutorial](https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-grid-layout/) for using the `QGridLayout` class. You would want to use this instead of the `QVBoxLayout` class. Here is another [link that helps explain](https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/start/layouts/) the different layouts and behaviors.